# IntelliJ does not show 'Class' when we right click and select 'New'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

We're creating a new project in IntelliJ and must have something wrong because when we right click on a directory, select *New* and then get the context menu, Java based options are not shown. Currently get things like File, some HTML options, XML options.

We have assumed so far it's something we haven't configured correctly in the Project/Module configuration. The new module we are talking about is part of a multi module project. We created it using a Maven web archetype.

Any help configuring the project nature?

**Edit: The answer is basic:** *'That moment when you realise somethings not working because you haven't been clicking 'Apply'... :) We had a good laugh at ourselves when we discovered this'*

Comment: In my case package name was invalid. `int.project.mypackage`. `int` is not allowed in package name.

Answer (score 460, accepted):

The directory or one of the parent directories must be marked as `Source Root` (In this case, it appears in blue).

If this is not the case, right click your root source directory -> Mark As -> Source Root.

Comment: If it is your test directory, mark it as the `Test Source Root` (it will appear in green)

Comment: 'Mark Directory As' is not available in the menu of my version of Android, version 2.1. Any workarounds ?

Comment: Also, intellj-idea automatically recognize folder as source root when we have structure in such way: **src/main/java**

Comment: IntelliJ makes some really questionable design decisions.

Comment: Very useful 

Answer (score 78):

This can also happen if your package name is invalid.

For example, if your "package" is `com.my-company` (which is not a valid Java package name due to the dash), IntelliJ will prevent you from creating a Java Class in that package.

Comment: This... this worked. Changed the dash to an underscore and it worked immediately.

Comment: I had named a package Enum and that was my issue

Comment: Thank you! I tried deleting `*.iml` and `.idea`, invalidating caches to no avail...  I was getting convinced that it spotted my python files first (I have two scripts for my `Dockerfile` which happen to be placed first in the project) and decided to mark my whole project as a Python project...

Comment: Just like Arun (lowercase though), I was creating the package name as "enum". Creating it as "enums" solved the problem. I wish it could show in the New submenu a warning that "enum" (or whatever) is an invalid package name

Comment: package name cannot contain a reserved keyword. Something like `com.example.package` is not valid nor `com.example.class`.

Comment: This really helped me, I replaced dash with underscore and solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My package was called "enum" and it works after I changed it to "type".

Answer (score 21):

you need to mark your directory as source root (right click on the parent directory)

and then compile the plugin (it is important )

as result you will be able to add classes and more

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you open your module settings (**F4**) you can nominate which paths contain 'source'. Intellij will then mark these directories in blue and allow you to add classes etc.

In a similar fashion you can highlight test directories for unit tests.

Answer (score 7):

Project Structure->Modules->{Your Module}->Sources->{Click the folder named java in src/main}->click the blue button which img is a blue folder,then you should see the right box contains new item(Source Folders).All be done;

Comment: Thanks! this worked. For newbies searching for **Project Structure**, you can find it from **File** menu or press **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S** in windows.

Answer (score 4):

I will share another interesting point. If you try to create a package with the reserved keyword then it will be treated as a normal directory and not a package. I was having this issue where I was creating a package named import and it was converting that to a directory.

[image: A sample of mine]

Comment: Same here with "enum"

Comment: Same `switch` here

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is that the project name is not acceptable. For example, creating a project with spaces in the name does not block the project creation but the proper sources are not marked and when those are marked manually, I still was unable to create classes. Recreating the project with hyphens (-) instead of spaces corrected the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark your java directory as Source Root ,

1. Right Click on Java directory
2. Select ***Mark Directory*** as option and click on the sub menu option ***Source Root***

[image: Mark Java directory as Source root]

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue too. Invalidating Caches/Restart did the trick for me. Please upvote so the the IntelliJ folks take this more seriously. This gives the IDE a terrible UI/UX experience.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203100

Comment: It's 2024 and invalidating the cache and restarting still sometimes does the trick. 

Comment: Just ran into this on 2023.3 and invalidating cache and restart was the only fix. Tried refreshing gradle, repairing IntelliJ, restarting. Nothing worked except a invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not creating a package name which is same as predefined keywords in java like enum, int, long etc.

In my case I was trying to create a class under "enum" package. As soon as I changed package name to "enums" I was able to create class in it.

Answer (score 1):

There is another case where 'Java Class' don't show, maybe some reserved words exist in the package name, for example:

> com.liuyong.package.**case**
>
> com.liuyong.**import**.package

It's the same reason as @kuporific 's answer: the package name is invalid.

Comment: Hi Liu Yong. As you say, this is the same reason mentioned in another answer. If you believe that answer could be improved perhaps you can either edit it, or add your reply as a comment on that answer.

Comment: As a result, could I please ask you to delete this answer as IMO it is a duplicate answer

Answer (score 1):

If you just created your project, **let IntelliJ finish indexing** your project.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the people already gave the answer but this one is just for making someone's life easier.

TL;DR

[image: Screenshot of how to add test sources]

You must add the test folder as source.

1. Right click on java directory under test
2. Mark it as Tests
3. Add src/test/java in Test Source Folders

Thats it, IntelliJ will consider them as test source.

Comment: Does this answer respond to the question or answer something else?

Comment: Manoj I'm sure your answer has some substance, but could you add some words to describe what you are trying to communicate in the picture. I cannot immediately see what you are trying to say with the picture.

Comment: Hi Manoj, the edits look good but, & I could be mistaken, this is an expansion of an existing answer. You are free to edit the previously existing answer. I do like how yours has turned out but as a principle the moderators of this site try to avoid duplication of work (a key computer science goal except I guess in the cloud )

Comment: As the answer looks like a duplicate I'll need to flag it for closing but I do recommend adding your formatting and image edits to the leading answer as I do think they look good and are an addition. That is, even if the content is a duplicate, the effort could help and be redeemed in other locations

Comment: Hi Manoj, Ive had a think overnight and I think your answer could be instead an edit to the original answer. I like the visual approach. If I get time I'l try to come back and do the edit myself to preserve your work. Thank you for your contributions.