# Intellij IDEA code completion does not suggest classes coming from maven dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

This may sound stupid but here I go (there's no silly question after all, right?): I'm working on a JAVA Maven module with IntelliJ IDEA and the code completion feature works fine suggesting classes from both my module and the JDK.

However, the code completion feature does not seem to be aware of classes coming from Maven dependencies my module depends on.

For instance, my module depends on Maven dependencies such as *joda-time*.
The code completion popup does not suggest classes such as *LocalDate*.

Here's my code completion configuration:

[image: code-completion-configuration]

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can IntelliJ detect `joda-time` in your code (i.e. does your code compile in the IDE)?

Comment: Does code completion work for _any_ classes?

Comment: My whole module does compile. Code completion does work for classes from the SDK, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462940/intellij-code-completion-not-working-for-new-java-classes).  Possible causes are your POM file or IntelliJ running in power save mode.

Comment: I checked: the power save mode is disabled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the solution:

1. Clicked on `File > Invalide caches/restart`
2. Chose `Invalidate and Restart`
3. After restarting IntelliJ rebuild indexes from scratch and code completion works like a charm.

Comment: I am still getting bugs witht the latest intellij (183.5912.21), invalidating caches and restarting sometimes works but not always

Answer (score 0):

[image: Intellij right top]

If it is a Gradle or Maven Project As shown in the picture, you may need to import your project build.gradle file if Gradle or maven bom.xml file if Maven. It will sync your project and may download required files from gradle or maven server.

@SenzMate Iot Intelligence