# Intellji Code Completion not working (Community edition 1.5)

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

Edit :

My Intellji Code Completion is not working. I read other posts about this ([Intellisense in IntelliJ no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518529/intellisense-in-intellij-no-longer-working) ; [IntelliJ Code Completion not working for new Java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462940/intellij-code-completion-not-working-for-new-java-classes)) but all their ideas did not work. My Power Save mode is turned off and my source root is set.

Back to my problem with an example: 
`int redValues = 234;` when I type `redValue` and I hit `control+space` it says no suggestion.

My Code Completion is the defautl config and I have this problem since the last update of Intellji.

Comment: Please also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891.

Comment: My Source Root is set

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: CrazyCoder I reworked, it hope now smd can help :-)

Comment: This information is not enough to provide help. Need the screencast/sample project/logs. It would be better if you [submit it as a ticket to support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new).

Comment: Have you tried file->invalidates caches and restart?

Comment: I have fixed my problem! My installation was corrupt. Thanks to everyone!