# Intellij Idea Code Completion not working

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I just started Intellij Idea ( version 13.1.4 )today and noticed code completion with ctrl + space doesnt work anymore. 
If i'm typing like a class the automatic popup still appears and i can autocomplete this way, but if i close the popup with esc i cannot open it with ctrl + space anymore.

My settings:

[image]

So Basic Completion is activated. 
I tryed:

- file-> invalid caches and restart
- power mode off and one

No difference. Any help appreciated cause it kinda makes me mad :)

Comment: Have you check the key mappings: settings -> keymap?

Comment: jep. reinstalling did the trick ...

Comment: i am using 2016-01 version, osx10.11.3, reinstall still can't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellisense in IntelliJ no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518529/intellisense-in-intellij-no-longer-working)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem.  Ended up being caused by me not having a directory marked as Sources Root.

To fix: right click on your src directory > Mark Directory As > Sources Root.