# Android Studio: Cannot import Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I tried to use a bitmap in my android project, importing `android.graphics.Bitmap`. But Bitmap class is missing. I can import other classes ,

`android.graphics.BitmapFactory`

`android.graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder`

`android.graphics.BitmapShader`

error images

[image]

I tried,

- Rebuilding project
- Cleaning project

But not helped. How can i solve this? Thank you.

Comment: More detail about the import failure/screenshot of the error along with the section of code which is causing the failure may help.

Comment: I added images. Please check.

Comment: Maybe check your sdk?

Comment: How to check SDK? I looked for Bitmap.java file and SDK have it

Comment: Please check that you do not have 'Power Saving Mode' on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518529/intellisense-in-intellij-no-longer-working

Comment: @Malinda I mean you download all related android sdk from sdk manager?

Comment: @DonalWu ; Thank you. I downloaded it recently

Comment: @MorrisChang: I checked the Power saving mode and it's off

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I  update  Android studio then

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
```

worked.

Comment: Yes. I think it was a SDK problem.