# IntelliJ File and Template Macro Missing

Tags: intellij-idea, tags, ide, visualforce, apex

I just updated my IntelliJ and have found that when I create a new class or page the auto completion tags are not generated anymore. Meaning that I get a blank page with no tags. I assume it was a Macro that was helping to generate these header and footer tags. Does anyone know if there is another way of re-instantiating this functionality? If the only way to do this is via File and Code Templates, does anyone have the macros for the tags? Thank you!!

Picture 1 is what the class looks like when I create a new class. I then have to manually add in the tags as you can see in picture 2. Before the update intellij was auto populating the class name and the brackets.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try pressing Ctrl + spacebar ?

Comment: @Junaid I am not sure what you mean. For auto completing?

Comment: Will this help ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518529/intellisense-in-intellij-no-longer-working

Comment: What tags do you mean? Can you provide an example? Do you mean HTML tags?

Comment: @CrazyCoder please see picture attachments. It is both HTML tags and class name generation. When I right click to make a new class, it prompts me for the new class name. When I create the new class name, the body of the class should auto generate the newly created class name ie: "public class ClassName { }"

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: @CrazyCoder it is APEX. I am using the IlluminatedCloud plugin with IntelliJ.

Comment: @Olivia you should contact support@illuminatedcloud.com for help.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you I will.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with support, it appears there is a bug in one version down from 2017.2.2 of intelliJ. 
After I updated my intelliJ, my templates were being populated again. Here is the link to the download:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows