# Why is there no help text when i write "." in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When i write "." in IntelliJ no text comes.
Heres what it looks like for me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wlKd.png)

And here is what im trying to get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC98f.png)

I have searched all over the place, but i just cant seem to find an answer...

Comment: [Intellisense in IntelliJ no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518529/intellisense-in-intellij-no-longer-working) This was the second result when I googled for [intellij code assist not working](https://www.google.com/search?q=intellij+code+assist+not+working)

Comment: maybe because `username` is unknown or invalid at that specific location (we cannot see the code, so just a guess)