# Why intelij does not recognize java project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I was working in one project then created new one and after opening the old one it is not recognized as java project. There is no option to create class in package (as you see on the pic), empty middle packages are not hidden but this option is set on.

[image: no Java Class item]

Why intelij-idea does not recognize java project?

Comment: right click "ru" folder. hit "Mark Directory As.." and choose "source"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852425/intellij-does-not-show-class-when-we-right-click-and-select-new

Comment: @flakes better to click on "main"

Comment: @talex oops ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @flakes, that does not work, folder becomes blue but there is still no Java Class in New menu option

Comment: @flakes, your first advice was correct, need to set "ru" folder as Source, but it does not work if the same is done to "main" folder)) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your project is fine. Your directory structure does not follow the common `/src/main/java` convention and you need to mark your directories manually.

In this case, you need to right-click on your directory and perform "Mark Directory As Sources Root"